# iOS drag and drop images

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I was trying show a bunch of images, one at once. User could swipe left or right to navigate, just like photo library.

What I did is, for example I have 6 images, create a scroll view to hold those 6 images, and using pan gesture to move it.

Am I doing right? Or is there another neat solution?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm asking am I doing right by using gesture? 
More specific, should I use UIScrollView to do this or I should use something else?

Update:

I finally figure out a way to do. Use UIPanGestureRecognizer and check the speed. if the speed is fast enough, then treat like swipe gesture. Will post code later.

Comment: What does this have to do with dragging and dropping images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIScrollView has a default gesture and does not need a new one.

Comment: So you means I should use UIScrollView but instead of using gestures, using uiscrollview delegate right?